# Pseudo elements in Sass variable?

Tags: variables, sass, pseudo-element

Can I use a pseudo element to declare a variable in Sass? I want my variable to be the first letter of a given string inside a list item. My watcher throws an error and won't compile.

Sass:

```
$firstLetter: li::first-letter


=newItem ($firstLetter)
  $m
    @extend %liStyle
    @if $firstLetter == "m"
      background-color: #3a495c
      color: white
      box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #14bbb1
      display: list-item
      font-family: sans-serif
      font-size: .889em
      border: 1px solid #ebeaec
    &:hover
      box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ffdc00
    &:active
      box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #d86969
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Variables must be of a specific type (string, integer, length, color, etc.), there is no "selector" type.  If you need to have a variable to contain a selector, then it needs to be quoted and treated as a string:

```
$firstLetter: "li::first-letter";

#{$firstLetter} {
  color: red;
}
```